# iOS - UITableView with text field in bottom cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, keyboard

I've got a table view (which has 15 cells) with a text view in the bottom cell.

When I try to enter text in the text view that is in the bottom cell, the keyboard is appearing over the cell/text view and I cannot see what is being typed.

How can I create a view similar to the contacts view where user can still scroll to bottom cell even when the keyboard appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Apple's [KeyboardAccessory](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code.

> The sample also shows how you can use the keyboard-will-show and keyboard-will-hide notifications to animate resizing a view that is obscured by the keyboard.

Comment: If its a regular view, i'd have done that. but this is table view and so not knowing how to do it

Comment: [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a subclass of [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html), so the above will work just fine.

Comment: the problem is that i've many text fields in table view. and so by default its scrollable. how can i get the text field postion and scroll the view accordingly?

Comment: Take a look at `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` in the [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.